# align a div next to one that uses margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

This is my first time on this forum and ill try to be clear as possible, i have a problem with creating a small website for my own, specifically with the header. Im trying to create a page which has a wrapper of 1024px center (margin: 0 auto;) and i would like 2 divs, on both sides of this wrapper where i can use another picture as background. My current css looks like this:

```
body, html      
background: url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#wrapper
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1024px;
}
#header {
width: 1024px;
height: 254px;
background-image: url(../images/header2.png);
background-repeat: none;
position: relative;
}
#header_right {
width: 50%;
right: 0;
background-image: url(../images/header_right2.png);
position: absolute;
height: 254px;
}
#header_left {
width: 50%;
left: 0px;
background-image: url(../images/header_left.png);
position: absolute;
background-position: right;
margin-left: -512px;
height: 254px;
}
```

and my html looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="header_right"></div><!--End header right!-->
<div id="header_left"></div><!--End header right!-->
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div><!--End header!-->
<div id="content"></div><!--End Content!-->
</div><!--End wrapper!-->
</body>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to have a header that continues on both left and right (both headers use different backgrounds), in this case it does work on the left, because im using a negative margin, since i use 50% width and exactly the half of the wrapper (-512px), this works, but if i would try to use a negative margin on the right (margin-right: -512px) this will extend the page on the right with an extra 512px, which is not my intention.

I've been googling all day but can't seem to find any answer to my question, also tried to make 3 divs with float: left , but couldnt figure out how to make 1 in the center with a width of 1024px and the rest 100% width, if anyone could help me out that would be really appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Consider using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) in future posts. It is easier to debug & show results with it.

Comment: thanks shadowscripter, ill keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure how you want it to look like, but I'll give it a shot.
If I'm way off, perhaps you could provide me with a schematic of sorts?

In any case, the example given below does not use your specific code, but it should give you an idea of how it's done.

---

Result: [image: first example]

The left and right headers are "infinite", in that they always fill the entire page's width.
The middle header covers up the rest. If you've got background images you can use `background-position` to position them so that they align with the middle header's left and right edges.

---

Code | [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gLRv/)

HTML

```html
<div class='side_wrapper'>
    <div class='left_header'></div><div class='right_header'></div>
</div>
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='content'>
    Content here
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.header, .side_wrapper, .left_header, .right_header{
    height: 100px;
}

.header, .content{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.side_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.left_header, .right_header{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.left_header{
    background-color: blue;
}

.right_header{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.header{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.content{
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i deleted previous message because i already found my previous answer, i will get it to work now, many thanks!

Comment: @GMolenaar Great! Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You want the two header out of the wrappper and aside of it right?
If im right, try this:

```
<body>

<div id="header_left"></div><!--End header right!-->
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div><!--End header!-->
<div id="content"></div><!--End Content!-->
</div><!--End wrapper!-->
<div id="header_right"></div><!--End header right!-->
</body>
```

and :

```
display: inline; float: left;
```

in each element(header-left, header-right, wrappper), and get out of the negative margin

Comment: hi ark, thanks for your answer, i tried that, but wouldn't fix it, should i leave the width: 50% tho? and what about the positioning of the 3 divs?

Comment: hi ark, thanks for your quick response, that did work! the last question is that both sides dont have an specific width and should be as long as the page is , the wrapper is set on 1024px, both sides need to be 'infinite' (as width as your screen is)

Comment: also, the wrapper should be aligned in the center of the page at any time, i hope my question is clear, once again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In you divs use float:left; this should mean that within a wrapper as long as there is enough space they will float next to each other for example
css:

```
#divWrapper
{
width:500px;
float:left;
background-color:red;
}
#divLeft
{
width:250px;
float:left;
background-color:blue;
}
#divRight
{
width:250px;
float:left;
background-color:green;
}
```

Html

```
<div id "divWrapper">
   <div id = "divLeft">content here</div>
   <div id = "divRight">content here</div>
</div><!--this is the end of the wrapper div -->
```

A really good tool to use for manipulating css is Firebug in Firefox https://getfirebug.com/

if you want a centre div try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzfu2/1/

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer anna, the problem is that there need to be 3 divs and only 1 with a fixed width (1024px), the sides on both sides need to be as long as the page is long

Comment: Hi do you mean the height or width by long? i have updated this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzfu2/5/ so that the wrapper has a fixed width and the divs inside are percentages of it  or the centre div has a fixed width with two divs at the side http://jsfiddle.net/kzfu2/6/